# SWT, styledText, get x coordinates for certain line

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-cdt, styledtext

I am working on plug-in for eclipse CDT editor, which is an overlay that can highlight certain parts of code. I have access to opened **CEditor** (and its IDocument), and from it also to **StyledText**. I also have a **character offset** of parts i want to highlight. 
 Currently i have PaintListener over editor and i am able to draw over(I make transparent image onto which i paint highlighting, then set it as text background, i.e. `styledText.setBackgroundImage(newImage);` ). From styledText i am also able to get information about text height and text vertical position (scrolling included) i.e. i am able to highlight line of code, but i want to highlight only part of that line.

```java
gc.fillRectangle(OFFSETX1, styledText.getLinePixel(LINE), OFFSETX2, tyledText.getLineHeight());
```

How can i get X in pixels(OFFSETX1,OFFSETX2) from character offset ??(Is it possible to get it from StyledText ? ). I have been searching StyledText API for hours, but couldn't find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StyledText.getLocationAtOffset`

> Returns the x, y location of the upper left corner of the character
>   bounding box at the specified offset in the text. The point is
>   relative to the upper left corner of the widget client area.

```java
Point loc = styledText.getLocationAtOffset(character offset);
```